# SQL over TLS using Let's Encrypt on Raspberry pi

Tags: sql, ssl, raspberry-pi

I want to be able to connect to a database hosted on a Raspberry Pi (mysql-server) from a C# application. In the real world professionals use a Webservice for this, but I want to use the SQL-connector for C#.

I successfully pulled this off using a certificate from Comodo.
See https://tutorials.pieterjan.pro/?a=Webdesign_Hosting_ExternHosten_HTTPS_SSL_SQL-TLS&lang=nl

I already installed a certificate from Let's Encrypt for pieterjan.pro. But when I configure mysql to use this certificate it doesn't work. While I actually did the same thing.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

contains:

```
ssl
ssl-cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/fullchain.pem
ssl-key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/privkey-nopassword.key
```

The key-file has been reproduced with openSSL, So it wouldn't be password-protected. The paths to the cert and key are correct. Why can't I use SQL over TLS using a LetsEncrypt Certificate?

```
pi@pieterjan:~ $ mysql -p -u root
Enter password:
mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                      |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | DISABLED                                                   |
| have_ssl      | DISABLED                                                   |
| ssl_ca        |                                                            |
| ssl_capath    |                                                            |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/fullchain.pem          |
| ssl_cipher    |                                                            |
| ssl_key       | /etc/letsencrypt/live/pieterjan.pro/privkey-nopassword.key |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You might get a better / quicker answer on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Forgot to mention: I also tried with a OpenSSL pem-output-file instead of key-output-file

Comment: What exactly do you think the ssl keys in mysql are going to do?

Comment: I'm just wondering why it does work using a Comodo certificate while it's not working using a LetsEncrypt certificate. Could it be that the Root Certificate of LetsEncrypt is not yet trusted by the mysql-connector that I'm using in C#? (ref Chain Of Trust). I've been using [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) this connector